# Output file lines from last to first in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I want to display the last 10 lines of my log file, *starting with the last line*- like a normal log reader. I thought this would be a variation of the tail command, but I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: you mean starting from the last line, then last line -1, last line -2 etc...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using `tail -r`, which worked on my OSX (`tac` doesn't)

```
tail -r -n10
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it is not GNU specific and avoids a "useless use of cat". http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Comment: Does not work `root@elk:/# tail -r -n1 /var/log/logstash-test-output.log 
tail: invalid option -- 'r'`

Comment: @KarlMorrison This won't work for non-BSD tail commands.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8017478/616644) for more help...

Answer (score 58):

**GNU (Linux)** [uses the following](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#index-BSD-tail):

```
tail -n 10 <logfile> | tac
```

`tail -n 10 <logfile>` prints out the last 10 lines of the log file and `tac` (cat spelled backwards) reverses the order.

**BSD (OS X)** of `tail` uses the `-r` option:

```
tail -r -n 10 <logfile>
```

**For both cases**, you can try the following:

```
if hash tac 2>/dev/null; then tail -n 10 <logfile> | tac; else tail -n 10 -r <logfile>; fi
```

**NOTE:** The [GNU manual states](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#index-BSD-tail) that the BSD `-r` option "can only reverse files that are at most as large as its buffer, which is typically 32 KiB" and that `tac` is more reliable.  If buffer size is a problem and you cannot use `tac`, you may want to consider using [@ata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020488/616644) which writes the functionality in bash.

Comment: I'm sure this is right, but looks like the 'tac' command doesn't exist on OSX shell...

Comment: @Yarin See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-lines-in-a-file for some alternatives to `tac`, not all of which are portable.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ding you for "useless use of cat" http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html since tail has the option -r to reverse the order. So `tail -r -n 10 <logfile>` is the better choice. As a bonus tail -r works on non-GNU systems like OSX, Solaris, AIX, etc.

Comment: @RichardBronosky Nice link, I've edited my answer to also include the `-r` option.

Comment: @RickSmith respectable humility, friend. I received the award in 1999 and have been diligent ever since. Also, I was GNU-only from 1995-1999 before getting plunged into Posix systems and had to relearn a lot because the admins refused to install all the sugar I was used to.

Comment: GNU tail does not have the `-r` option, see https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#index-BSD-tail

Answer (score 16):

`tac` does what you want. It's the reverse of `cat`.

`tail -10 logfile | tac`

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray file
lines=$(( ${#file[@]} - 1 ))
for (( line=$lines, i=${1:-$lines}; (( line >= 0 && i > 0 )); line--, i-- )); do
    echo -ne "${file[$line]}"
done
```

> ./tailtac 10 < somefile
>
> ./tailtac -10 < somefile
>
> ./tailtac 100000 < somefile
>
> ./tailtac < somefile

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect methods to print output in reverse order

```
tail -n 10 <logfile>  | tac
```

Comment: What are the asterisks for?

Comment: Including the word "perfect" is just inviting criticism.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution is

```
_tac_echo() {
  IFS=$'\n'
  echo "${BASH_ARGV[*]}"
}

_tac () {
  local -a lines
  readarray -t lines
  shopt -s extdebug
  _tac_echo "${lines[@]}"
  shopt -u extdebug
}

cat <<'EOF' | _tac
1 one line[of] smth
2 two line{of} smth
3 three line(of) smth
4 four line&of smth
EOF
```

which prints

```
4 four line&of smth
3 three line(of) smth
2 two line{of} smth
1 one line[of] smth
```