# Output last file lines in reverse order- from last to first- in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

Looking for a PHP solution to:

1. Perform 'tail' type shell command on a file
2. Perform 'tac' type shell command on a file

In other words, display the last lines of a file in reverse order, from last to first, like a log reader.

I [just asked this question for Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017456/output-file-lines-from-last-to-first-in-bash), hoping I could run a shell_exec(), but the recommended method - tac - doesn't work on my OSX.

Comment: The obvious solution is to abandon OSX. Of course, I kid. No, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

A non-efficient way would be to fgets() the whole file into an array and then reverse it (Not good on big files).

OR

http://tekkie.flashbit.net/php/tail-functionality-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functionality of `tac` on OSX by using the `-r` option to `tail`

```
tail -r file
Line3
Line2
Line1
```