# How to write a tail script without the tail command

Tags: bash, unix

How would you achieve this in bash.  It's a question I got asked in an interview and I could think of answers in high level languages but not in shell.

As I understand it, the real implementation of tail seeks to the end of the file and then reads backwards.

Comment: "in bash" "in shell" do you mean any external commands are not allowed to use? like sed/awk/wc ?

Comment: @t0mmyt That real implementation without using a buffer and just seeking is not possible with stdin or pipes. As for reading backwards I'm not sure about that but anything's possible if you're already using arrays. Please check my solution which is written in pure bash. I think it's more than enough to prove the concept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main idea is to keep a fixed-size buffer and to remember the last lines. Here's a quick way to do a tail using the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

SIZE=5
idx=0

while read line
do
    arr[$idx]=$line
    idx=$(( ( idx + 1 ) % SIZE )) 
done < text

for ((i=0; i<SIZE; i++))
do
    echo ${arr[$idx]}
    idx=$(( ( idx + 1 ) % SIZE )) 
done
```

Comment: I think this needs to be fixed a bit: If you use a `text` of 6 lines, for example, the last line will get wrapped as the first line in the output.

Comment: @MannyD Yup, it probably has more bugs

Comment: @MannyD I fixed that one ( but introduced an ugly bashism :-( ). Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Glad this wasn't deleted as it was a very good answer. You could also just output in one loop where you loop from 1..$SIZE but increment `IDX` the exact same way you do in the `read` and use that to index the array.

Comment: No need for `$` in math context; `for (( i=0; i<idx; i++ ))` needs no `$idx`. Also, `idx=$((idx + 1 ))` is valid in POSIX sh, and considerably easier to read than messing with expr; likewise for `idx=$(( ( idx + 1 ) % SIZE ))`.

Comment: ...also, `seq` is a nonstandard tool, mostly Linux-only. Better, and POSIX-compliant, would be: `while [ $(( ( x += 1 ) <= SIZE )) -ne 0 ]; do ...; done`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, great comments. I'm just a beginner in shell scripting, feel free to edit.

Comment: Since you're using `#!/bin/bash` in the shebang, I'd actually prefer the bash-only syntax you used earlier -- `for x in ((i=0; i<SIZE; i++))` -- as it's considerably easier to read.

Comment: This solution does not play well if the output is less than the buffer size. We could add: `[[ ! -z ${arr[$idx]} ]] && echo ${arr[$idx]`

Answer (score 7):

If all not-tail commands are allowed, why not be whimsical?

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -r "$1" ] && exec < "$1"

tac | head | tac
```

Comment: `exit $?` is redundant -- the shell's default exit status is that of the most recently run command.

Comment: You're right, of course. Out of long habit, I usually have my scripts say "exit" as they're heading out the door, unnecessary as that is.

Answer (score 4):

Use `wc -l` to count the number of lines in the file. Subtract the number of lines you want from this, and add 1, to get the starting line number. Then use this with `sed` or `awk` to start printing the file from that line number, e.g.

```
sed -n "$start,\$p"
```

Comment: -1 That's not pure Bash at all. (Mine appears to be the second downvote, though.)

Comment: AFAIC, standard Unix tools like `wc` and `sed` count. "Pure bash" is practically never used.

Comment: @tripleee: It definitely doesn't make a case of -1. OP never wrote `pure bash` requirement.

Comment: @Barmar if `tail` is not usable in the context of the interview, I'm pretty sure sed or awk or any other similar tool is unacceptable

Comment: I guess it depends on precisely how the question is worded. I.e. whether they said "only bash is available" or "tail is not available".

Answer (score 3):

There's this:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray file
lines=$(( ${#file[@]} - 1 ))
for (( line=$(($lines-$1)), i=${1:-$lines}; (( line < $lines && i > 0 )); line++, i-- )); do
    echo -ne "${file[$line]}"
done
```

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020488/851273

You pass in the number of lines at the end of the file you want to see then send the file via stdin, puts the entire file into an array, and only prints the last # lines of the array.

Comment: You undo to remove the part of that answer that prints them in reverse order.

Comment: @JonLin Doesn't this print in reverse order?

Comment: @rici I was surprised to see your simple code and was wanting to apply it with mine when I noticed that it doesn't work if `L > C (${#file[@]})` in `"${file[@]:(-L)}"`; but we could further improve it with `printf "%s" "${A[@]:(C > L ? C - L : 0)}"`. However the immediate use of all data to one command gave me an idea that we could instead not use `readarray` and limit the buffer to N lines only by using a read loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of in “pure” shell is to do a `while read` linewise on the whole file into an array variable with indexing modulo *n*, where *n* is the number of tail lines (default 10) — i.e. a circular buffer, then iterate over the circular buffer from where you left off when the `while read` ends. It's not efficient or elegant, in any sense, but it'll work and avoids reading the whole file into memory. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                 

incmod() {
    let i=$1+1
    n=$2

    if [ $i -ge $2 ]; then
        echo 0
    else
        echo $i
    fi
}

n=10
i=0
buffer=
while read line; do
    buffer[$i]=$line
    i=$(incmod $i $n)
done < $1

j=$i
echo ${buffer[$i]}
i=$(incmod $i $n)
while [ $i -ne $j ]; do
    echo ${buffer[$i]}
    i=$(incmod $i $n)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I would give if I were actually asked this question in an interview:

> What environment is this where I have `bash` but not `tail`?  Early boot scripts, maybe?  Can we get [`busybox`](http://www.busybox.net/) in there so we can use the full complement of shell utilities?  Or maybe we should see if we can squeeze a stripped-down Perl interpreter in, even without most of the modules that would make life a whole lot easier.  You know [`dash`](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/) is much smaller than `bash` and perfectly good for scripting use, right?  That might also help.  If none of that is an option, we should check how much space a statically linked C mini-`tail` would need, I bet I can fit it in the same number of disk blocks as the shell script you want.

If that doesn't convince the interviewer that it's a silly question, then I go on to observe that I don't believe in using bash extensions, because the only good reason to write anything complicated in shell script nowadays is if total portability is an overriding concern.  By avoiding anything that isn't portable even in one-offs, I don't develop bad habits, *and* I don't get tempted to do something in shell when it would be better done in a real programming language.

Now the thing is, in truly portable shell, arrays may not be available.  (I don't actually know whether the POSIX shell spec has arrays, but there certainly are legacy-Unix shells that don't have them.) So, if you *have* to emulate `tail` using only shell builtins and it's got to work everywhere, this is the best you can do, and yes, it's hideous, because you're writing in the wrong language:

```
#! /bin/sh

a=""
b=""
c=""
d=""
e=""
f=""

while read x; do
    a="$b"
    b="$c"
    c="$d"
    d="$e"
    e="$f"
    f="$x"
done

printf '%s\n' "$a"
printf '%s\n' "$b"
printf '%s\n' "$c"
printf '%s\n' "$d"
printf '%s\n' "$e"
printf '%s\n' "$f"
```

Adjust the number of variables to match the number of lines you want to print.

The battle-scarred will note that `printf` is not 100% available either.  Unfortunately, if all you have is `echo`, you are up a creek: some versions of `echo` cannot print the literal string "`-n`", and others cannot print the literal string "`\n`", and even figuring out which one you have is a bit of a pain, particularly as, if you don't have `printf` (which *is* in POSIX), you probably don't have user-defined functions either.

(N.B. The code in this answer, sans rationale, was originally posted by user 'Nirk' but then deleted under downvote pressure from people whom I shall charitably assume were not aware that some shells do not have arrays.)

Comment: No need for charitable interpretation -- the question is explicitly tagged `bash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But that's silly.  If you have `bash` then there is no plausible situation where you don't also have `tail`.  (Actually I think the entire question is silly.  I *have* actually seen a real-world situation where `cat` wasn't available - very early boot scripts in Solaris 2.5, which put nearly everything in `/usr` - and that was one of the horribly limited shells I'm thinking of.  But nowadays there is no reason not to put `busybox` in that kind of environment, giving you the full complement of utilities.)

Comment: It's an interview question (and explicitly described as such up front). It's not supposed to make sense in the real world.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interview questions that don't make sense in the real world are bad questions.  (See edits.)

Answer (score 0):

This script somehow imitates `tail`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

LENGTH=10

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    --)
        FILES+=("${@:2}")
        break
        ;;
    -+([0-9]))
        LENGTH=${1#-}
        ;;
    -n)
        if [[ $2 != +([0-9]) ]]; then
            echo "Invalid argument to '-n': $1"
            exit 1
        fi
        LENGTH=$2
        shift
        ;;
    -*)
        echo "Unknown option: $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        FILES+=("$1")
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done

PRINTHEADER=false

case "${#FILES[@]}" in
0)
    FILES=("/dev/stdin")
    ;;
1)
    ;;
*)
    PRINTHEADER=true
    ;;
esac

IFS=

for I in "${!FILES[@]}"; do
    F=${FILES[I]}

    if [[ $PRINTHEADER == true ]]; then
        [[ I -gt 0 ]] && echo
        echo "==> $F <=="
    fi

    if [[ LENGTH -gt 0 ]]; then
        LINES=()
        COUNT=0

        while read -r LINE; do
            LINES[COUNT++ % LENGTH]=$LINE
        done < "$F"

        for (( I = COUNT >= LENGTH ? LENGTH : COUNT; I; --I )); do
            echo "${LINES[--COUNT % LENGTH]}"
        done
    fi
done
```

Example run:

```
> bash script.sh -n 12 <(yes | sed 20q) <(yes | sed 5q)
==> /dev/fd/63 <==
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
y

==> /dev/fd/62 <==
y
y
y
y
y
> bash script.sh -4 <(yes | sed 200q)
y
y
y
y
```