# copy to clipboard the last n commands in a terminal

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to copy to clipboard something like this

```
$ command1
$ command2
```

If you run history you will get the commands in reverse order, so I want to just skip a number of lines from the tail and replace the entry line number with '$'. As you probably suspect this is a very useful shorthand when having to log your workflow or write documentation.

Example:

```
$ history

 1340  pass
 1341  pass insert m clouds/cloud9
 1342  pass insert -m clouds/cloud9
 1343  sudo service docker start
 1344  history
```

So how do you turn that into:

```
$ sudo service docker start
$ pass insert -m clouds/cloud9
...etc
```

Comment: Do you know the `tac` command? And these other questions? [Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file) [Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017456/output-file-lines-from-last-to-first-in-bash)

Comment: I did not use it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use these;

```
 history | tac | awk 'NR>1&&NR<=3  {$1="$";print $0}'
```

> tac - concatenate and print files in reverse

`NR<=3` : means that the last two commands before history. 
`NR>1` : to delete history command in history
`$1="$"` : to replace line numbers to $

test :

```
$ echo first
first
$ echo second
second

$ history | tac | awk 'NR>1&&NR<=3  {$1="$";print $0}'
$ echo second
$ echo first
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning $1 works but it will leave a leading space

```
history | awk '{$1=""; print}'
```

If you want to copy this to the clipboard, you can use xclip

```
history | awk '{$1=""; print}' | xclip
```

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198169/2032943