# Prepend certain lines of file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, terminal

I'd like to create a script to comment out lines of my Mac OS X hosts file that contain `.com`. And also one to reverse it.

So this:

```
127.0.0.1    foo.com
127.0.0.1    bar.com
127.0.0.1    baz
127.0.0.1    qux
```

would become:

```
#127.0.0.1   foo.com
#127.0.0.1   bar.com
127.0.0.1    baz
127.0.0.1    qux
```

I looked around on Google and the sed man page and tried a few things with bash and sed, but I haven't come close.

`sed 's/^/^#/' | grep '.com' < hosts`

`grep '.com' | sed 's/^/^#/' < hosts`

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file

Comment: @Fredrik What does that have to do this this?

Comment: doh, nothing except OP stated "And also one to reverse it." hence the link above

Comment: @Fredrik I think he meant "undo it".

Comment: That's another interpretation which, when you state it sounds more reasonable :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed '/\.com/s/^/#/' < hosts
```

Interpretation:

- `/\.com/` - only perform the rest of the command on lines matching this regex
- `s/^/#/`  - insert `#` at the beginning of the line

If you want to replace the original file, use sed's `-i` option:

```
sed -i.bak '/\.com/s/^/#/' hosts
```

This will rename `hosts` to `hosts.bak` and create a new `hosts` with the updated contents.

To undo it, use:

```
sed -i.bak '/^#.*\.com/s/^#//' hosts
```

Comment: I think OP wants it to be saved onto a file cause if he wanted it at stdout he could have just added a `cat <file>` in front of his command and it would work

Comment: @noMAD He used input redirection, which is the same thing. But I updated my answer to show how to replace with sed.

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk '$2 ~ /.com/{$0 = "#"$0;}{print}' temp.txt
```

Output

```
#127.0.0.1    foo.com
#127.0.0.1    bar.com
127.0.0.1    baz
127.0.0.1    qux
```