# Order of git submodule foreach

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there anyway to tell `git submodule foreach` to run in the submodule order specified in the `.gitmodules`? It seems to run alphabetically.

I want to the foreach command to run in th same order the submodules were added.

Comment: Is creating a bash script to feed correctly-ordered submodules to `git submodule update` a non-starter? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14846967/2449857) discusses the theme.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no solution using `git` but a simple line of bash makes the job:

You extract the list of submodules with sed, then you read it line by line and execute what you want.

```
cat .gitmodules | sed -n 's/.*path = //p' | { while read project; do  everything you want execute with each $project; done; }
```

It respects the order that was in your gitmodules file