# Customise output of git commands

Tags: git

When I type `git status` (with `advice.statusHints` = `False`) I get something like:

```
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  new file: file1
Changed not staged for commit:
  modified: file2
Untracked files:
  file3
```

Is it possible to customise this printed output so it could look something like:

```
On branch main
$$
  new file: file1
**
  modified: file2
%% 
  file3
```

This is just an example, but it could make things more concise.
Is it possible to do anything like this?

Comment: You could add the `--porcelain` flag and parse the output manually.

Comment: Some Git commands have very flexible outputs, and some don't. `git status` is in between: there are no formatting directives (unlike `git log --format` for instance) but there are the `--porcelain` and `--porcelain=v2` options for machine-readable output, and there is `--short` and there are several options for longer output. Read each commands' documentation to see what can be done for each command.

Comment: You could write a script and parse the output in any desired fashion, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22193283/341994