# Bash Awk, Reverse order of records

Tags: bash, awk

Hey everyone I am making an awk bash script that will take an input text file such as:

```
1111 Joe Brown
2222 Charlie Rogers
3333 Chris Williams
4444 Rob Black
```

And simply reverse the order of the rows, so output would be:

```
4444 Rob Black
3333 Chris Williams
2222 Charlie Rogers
1111 Joe Brown
```

I am getting a syntax error saying that there is an error near "(" and also that I have an extra "{" I cannot figure out what is happening here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END (for(i=NR; i>=1; i--)) printf("%s\n",a[i])}'
```

Comment: The simplest way to reverse the lines is `tac filename`. But that won't teach you any awk.

Comment: Well, you can do `tac filename | awk '1'` :)

Comment: You're missing the `{` bracket after `END` and there's a superfluous pair of `(` `)` around the `for` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse the order of lines in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file)

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use just sort(1) command.

```
sort -nr < input.txt
```

*Sort simply takes the input file and tries to sort it, taking the whitespace as a separator (which is our case), so it sorts the input by first column. If you need non-alphabetical sorting of the first column, the -n switch is needed (to sort numerically). The -r switch just reverses the output (ascending/descending).*

Comment: If you simply need to reverse the content of the file, you can use tac(1), which is present on the most unix systems, as @Dinesh mentioned.

Comment: I m trying to use this -r to reverse my sort. I am trying to sort by two columns simultaneously, ie names and logintime. i want to sort names in alphabetical order, but login time is to be latest login time first. using -r reverses both the sorts for each column.

Answer (score 4):

You have two extra brackets there. Correcting it:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} END {for(i=NR; i>=1; i--) printf("%s\n",a[i]);}' file
```

---

If you don't have to use `awk`,  you can do easily with: `tac file`

Answer (score 2):

If it is unix machine `tac` can be used.

Comment: `tac` is not a standard unix command, but is part of the Gnu coreutils (present in most linux distros).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk` variation:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0} END {while(i--) print a[i]}' file
4444 Rob Black
3333 Chris Williams
2222 Charlie Rogers
1111 Joe Brown
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl` solution:

```
$ perl -e 'print reverse <>' file
4444 Rob Black
3333 Chris Williams
2222 Charlie Rogers
1111 Joe Brown
```

**or** `sed`

```
$ sed '1!G;h;$!d' file
4444 Rob Black
3333 Chris Williams
2222 Charlie Rogers
1111 Joe Brown
```