# re-writing a csv file to a new file upside down in python

Tags: python-3.x

i'm looking to create a new CSV file from the first file, 
but the last line in the first file is the first line in the second file and so forth, until all the lines/rows are reversed.

cheers
Jon

Comment: does it need to be done in python? Why not just a [shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742466/how-can-i-reverse-the-order-of-lines-in-a-file)? e.g. `tail -r data.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python only:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('reversed_data.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for l in reversed(lines):
        f.write(l)
```

Or via shell:

```
tail -r data.csv > reverse_data.csv
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. i had been stuffing around with skip and nrows, and knew there was a much simpler way.