# view the file from bottom to top

Tags: unix, cat

HI,

I know that `cat` prints the contents of the file on screen.

i never worked on linux.But i am aware that `tac` is the command to show the file from bottom to top.I am not even sure whether tac is on unix.Atleast on my unix box its not present.
i want to know is there a simple command unix which gives the output from bottom to top?

i am expecting like below :

```
<command> file_name;
```

I know this can be done using some tools like `awk`,`sed`.
but could anyone please tell me a most simple command to perform that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tac` is in GNU coreutils, and is presently the only single file executable that does what you want. If you don't have `tac` installed you'll need to use a slower alternative, like the ones outlined at [How to reverse lines of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418280/filter-to-reverse-lines-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 3):

The Unix equivalent of

```
tac
```

is

```
tail -r
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tail -r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29)

This probably should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am on Lubuntu here and my `tail` does not have the `-r` option. Now I even know why: the [POSIX specification for the tail command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) does *not* list a `-r` option, hence it must be an (unofficial?) extension (presumedly not even a GNU extension).

Answer (score 1):

**tac** : Tac is opposite to **cat** in the sense that the output it produces is presented in a way that the last line is displayed first, then the second last line, and so on.

[image]

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-tac-command/